# How to get the number of vectors in a list that contains at least one occurrence of an element?

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors A (for example):

```
A <- list( c(1,2,3,4,5), c(2,4,6,8,10), c(1,3,5,7,9) );
```

In the above example, I want to know how many vectors in A contain (for instance) at least one occurrence of 3. The answer is 2 since `A[[1]]` and `A[[3]]` both contain 3.

We can, of course, do this using a **for loop** by incrementing a count variable for each vector in the list that contains the specified element. Is there a function that I can use in R without the need of using a loop?

Comment: 3 questions: a) can/should we assume that the number of elements in your list is always the same (5 here)? And more importantly, b) can the numbers repeat themselves within a list element? Meaning can `A[[1]]` be `1,2,3,4,3,5` for example? c) are the numbers always > 0?

Comment: a) a vector can be of any size, size >= 0.
b) Yes. 
c) Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum(sapply(A, function(x) 3 %in% x))
```

Comment: Use recycling to be a little more concise: `sum(mapply(`%in%`,3,A))`. (note this looks weird on SO because of backticks).

Comment: I'd prefer `sum(sapply(A, "%in%", x=3))` as it does not recycle.